# MDX Query to Calculated Field

Tags: mdx

I am trying to convert the following MDX query to calculated member in the cube:

```
SELECT 
  Hierarchize
  (
    Tail([TE Month].[TE Month].members,4)
  ) ON Rows
 ,{
    [Measures].[Monthly- Project Cost],[Measures].[Monthly-On Time Project]

  } ON columns
FROM [CUBE];
```

I have tried some queries but none of them are working.

Answer (score 0):

You have two measures in your question.

Considering just one measure:

```
SELECT 
  Hierarchize(Tail([TE Month].[TE Month].MEMBERS,4)) ON ROWS
 ,{
    [Measures].[Monthly- Project Cost]
  } ON COLUMNS
FROM [CUBE];
```

You can move the logic into a WITH clause which should help map out what is required in your cube script:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [TE Month].[All].[NewCalcMemeber] AS 
    Aggregate
    (
      Tail
      (
        [TE Month].[TE Month].MEMBERS
       ,4
      )
     ,[Measures].[Monthly- Project Cost]
    ) 
SELECT 
  [TE Month].[All].[NewCalcMemeber] ON ROWS
FROM [CUBE];
```

---

**EDIT**

In your cube you can create a couple of stuctures:

- Custom sets
- Calculated members

Comment: I am trying to use the formula in my cube, where the syntax like Select does not work. can you help me with the formula for Cube. And I am not looking for Aggregate Value. I am looking for a table like month be arranged sequentially and the measures value against them